# Using multiple images per data point in a binary classification CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm making a CNN model to categorise MRI brain scans into Alzheimer's and Healthy groups.

It currently seems as though it's overfitting, and we have tried a lot of tricks in the book to fix this issue.

One method I'd now like to try - but have no experience in - is using multiple images of the brain scan per data point.

For example:

I download the brain scans in .nii format and conver them into a series of png files. Each png file is of the same scan at different points in time. With my current model, I have simply deleted all but one of these images per brain scan, making my model easier to work with.

What I'd now like to try is to use multiple images - say 5 to begin with - for each sample in my dataset.

How would I go about achieving this by altering my current model?

**I do not want to use the data augmentation feature of the ImageDataGenerator, I'd like to use existing files which I have stored on my computer.**

I'd appreciate any and all responses as the current model is sitting at ~80% training accuracy and 55% val accuracy.

```py
# Use ImageDataGenerator to create 3 lots of batches
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255).flow_from_directory(directory=train_path,
        target_size=(80,80), classes=['cn', 'ad'], batch_size=100,
            color_mode="rgb")
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255).flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path,
        target_size=(80,80), classes=['cn', 'ad'], batch_size=100,
            color_mode="rgb")
# test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(
#     rescale=1/255).flow_from_directory(directory=test_path,
#         target_size=(224,224), classes=['cn', 'ad'], batch_size=10,
#             color_mode="rgb")

imgs, labels = next(train_batches)

# Test to see normalisation has occurred properly
print(imgs[1][8])

# Define method to plot MRIs
def plotImages(images_arr):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 10, figsize=(20,20))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    for img, ax in zip( images_arr, axes):
        ax.imshow(img)
        ax.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# Plot a sample of MRIs
plotImages(imgs)

# # Define the model
# # VGG16
# model = Sequential()
# model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(160,160,3),filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
# model.add(Flatten())
# model.add(Dense(units=1024,activation="relu"))
# model.add(Dense(units=128,activation="relu"))
# model.add(Dense(units=2, activation="softmax"))

# # Model from the paper
# model = Sequential([
#     Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(160,160,3)),
#     Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
#     MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
#     Flatten(),
#     Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')
# ])

## Model from Dr Paul
# static_conv_layer=Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', padding = 'same')
#
# model = Sequential([
#     Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(32,32,3)),
#     MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
#     Dropout(0.1),
#     static_conv_layer,
#     MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
#     Dropout(0.1),
#     Flatten(),
#     Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')
# ])

# This model hits around 75% train acc, 54% val acc
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(80,80,3)),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
    # Dropout(0.1),
    # Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    # MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
    # Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    # MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')
])

# model = Sequential([
#     Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(160,160,3)),
#     Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
#     MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
#     Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
#     Flatten(),
#     Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')
# ])

## Basic model with dropouts
# model = Sequential([
#     Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same', input_shape=(224,224,3)),
#     MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
#     Dropout(0.1),
#     Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
#     MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
#     Dropout(0.2),
#     Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
#     MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
#     Dropout(0.3),
#     Flatten(),
#     Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')
# ])

# Summarise each layer of the model
print(model.summary())

# Compile and train the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=train_batches,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_batches),
    validation_data=valid_batches,
    validation_steps=len(valid_batches),
    epochs=20,
    verbose=1
)
```

Comment: This is my [favorite article](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-3-more-on-cnns-handling-overfitting-2bd5d99abe5d) (that I always refer to) on how to prevent overfitting and underfitting. :) Some tips include simplifying your model (removing neurons/layers) and adding [Dropout layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/). In your model, I also noticed that after your Flatten layer you don't have any more Dense layers. After Flatten, try adding a dense layer with 64-128 neurons.

Comment: @Landon I have tried simplifying my model to the point where it is only consisting of a single conv2d and max pooling layer. I've also tried adding dropout layers to no avail. I'll try the additional dense layer, but i really think the crux of the problem is not having enough images per data point, do you have any information on how to go about using multiple images per data point? Thanks either way!

Comment: Is your goal to prevent overfitting or to feed images in groups of 5 instead of individually?

Answer (score 0):

In order to incorporate multiple images in your model now, you can take your multiple images for each data point, the easiest thing would be to average them and you can try that. But, a better approach will be to apply dimensionality reduction on the multiple images.

First, it will consolidate all the features for each person and also, if number of images is different for each person, then, this would ease your training.

It would be better to compute the features outside and then, plug them into your model.

For that consider, PCA first.